# Trouble reaching open port

Tags: c, sockets

I've got a small program with a client and server. The server starts, connects to the client and receives a host and second port number from the client, then sends some information back to the client about it's directory. The function in the server that sends data back works something like this:

```
void sendStuff(char *host, char *port) {
    int sockfd, numbytes;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_info;
    socklen_t addr_size;

    size_t i = 0;
    int rv; 

    // clear hints
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    memset(&servinfo, 0, sizeof(servinfo));
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    }

    // create socket
    sockfd = socket(servinfo->ai_family, servinfo->ai_socktype, servinfo->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("There was an error creating your socket.");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
}

    // connect using socket
    int conn;
    conn = connect(sockfd, servinfo->ai_addr, servinfo->ai_addrlen);
    if(conn == -1) {
        perror("Error connecting to server.");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }


    send(sockfd, "hey!", strlen("hey!"), 0);

}
```

Currently testing over localhost, which is being printed as 16.2.197.67 on the client. That doesn't seem like a localhost IP, so I suppose I could be screwing up the host somehow. Connecting to the waiting socket over telnet works, but not through this function.

Comment: You are right, 16.2.197.67 is not a link-local address.  It might be nevertheless be the current address of one of the machine's own network interfaces, however.

Comment: You're right, @Rup, but the pointer is in fact what is being initialized, so that's the right size to use.  Personally, I'd have just written `servinfo = NULL`, or even just not worried about it.  `getaddrinfo` pays no attention to its value on input.

Comment: What does `ipconfig` (Windows) / `ifconfig` (Linux & Macos) have to say about local addresses?

Comment: @dgnuff I believe localhost is 127.0.0.1. It shows up in `ifconfig` and was my local IP in another program.

Comment: @Ja5onHoffman My apologies, I should have been a bit clearer.  What I was curious about is if the other IP address: `16.2.197.67` is showing anywhere in the output of `ifconfig`.  And if so, any hint as to what it's bound to.  on my system, I have a virtualbox VM running, so I see `127.0.0.1` localhost, `172.16.x.x` for my main NIC, and `192.168.10.1` for the virtualbox "virtual" adapter.

Comment: @dgnuff With both the client and server running, I don't see this IP in the output. Am I accidentally morphing the IP somewhere? Here - `inet_ntop(client_info.ss_family, (struct sockaddr*)&client_info, addr, sizeof addr);`

Comment: @Ja5onHoffman At this point, I don't know.  Other than taking a debugger to the problem and studying exactly what's in `servinfo` I'm out of ideas now.